# Replace WP logo with H1 using JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I need to replace `site_logo();` with `the_title( '<a href="http://example.com/"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></a>' );` using JS if possible, so that I don't edit the `header.php` directly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have a child theme, it would be best to create one so you can edit the theme templates without worring about losing your changes when theme is updated. This cannot be done with JS, as JS is front end and PHP is backend. You can replace the html that is outputed but not the PHP functions using JS

Comment: @Buttered_Toast is it possible to achieve that editing the frontend html and avoid creating a child theme?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that `site_logo();` is [tag:php] that generates some html.  If you know what that html is going generate, you can use js to replace the *rendered html*.  But you can't call `the_title()` (which I again *guess* is a php function) from javascript (without making an extra ajax call to a different end point)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```js
$("h1").replaceWith('<a href="http://example.com/"><h1 class="entry-title">replaceWith</h1></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
```